# How do I make curl to POST a parameter, reading its value from a file?

Tags: http, curl

I’m playing with [GitHub web hooks](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks) and I want to use curl to post some sample JSON. The request is supposed to contain a `payload` POST parameter with the JSON string as a value. As an example, this works:

```
$ curl --form payload='{"foo":1}' http://somewhere
```

But I need to read the JSON from a file (say `foo.json`). Replacing the JSON string by `@foo.json` posts the payload in the request body:

```
--------------------------8d0c6d3f9cc7da97
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="payload"; filename="foo.json"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{'foo':1}

--------------------------8d0c6d3f9cc7da97--
```

That’s not really what I want, I need the payload to be passed as a parameter. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe silly but try this:

```
cat foo.json | xargs -I % curl --form payload='%' http://example.com
```

Just wrote this little thing and it worked:

```
var=`cat some.json` && curl --form payload="$var" http://lvh.me/test/index.php
```

Comment: That doesn’t really work, as `xargs` runs curl for each line in `foo.json`. `-0` doesn’t help. Ideas?

Comment: Yeah duh -- sorry, submitted without trying it out. there must be a way, hold please :)

Comment: Allright, it’s a cludge, but it works, thank you. Still I would be interested in a simpler solution using just curl, if anyone knows.

Comment: me too :), glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an alternative Perl testing script. Pass the target URL as the first argument, feed the JSON to STDIN:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP;

my $target = shift @ARGV or die "Need a target URL";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $payload = do { local $/; <STDIN> };
my $response = $ua->post($target, { payload => $payload });
print $response->as_string;
```